# How to display discounted price?

Tags: price-range

This question is related to how to effectively show pricing information. The product I sell have a retail price, a product price (at certain discount off the retail price) and an offer price(which is at a even deeper discount than the product price). Moreover, the offer price is based on user action (like 3 purchases in the last month). All these information makes sense to the user. The question is how to arrange this information without being too overloaded. 
I am currently thinking the following:

Original Price: $100
Price was: $60
Price is: $40 (Extra discount for .....)

Please provide suggestions.

Comment: This question is not UX related.

Comment: @WilliamEdwards  this is exactly an UX question.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend something similar to Amazon :

[image]

You can use something like this :

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhAlTB.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Good suggestion, doing that you're making the user do the maths and see the difference. I'm having the same problem as Arnab Bhattacharya, to properly show discount on my home page and this helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would consider this a UX question, at the most part. For me, personally, I'd like to see a simple graphic that associates a sale item. A sale tag typically is the right graphic to display. You'd want to have a GIF or sliced image of the graphic in order to allow for a greater amount of data. To save time and space, I'd shorten the displayed data to only a few characters. $100 with a slash through it and $60 + an extra sales tag to show that $40 is taken off that. Also color code the tags to represent reg, sale, and discount. Hope that helps!

Comment: Would you mind explaining the reasoning behind your suggestions?  It makes the answer more objective.

Comment: Sure thing! My reason behind my suggestion is because of what I feel is a normal looking interface. When I think of an item that displays a price, I typically imagine it being compact. Nothing to noisy or extravagant. I guess that comes from all the e-commerce websites like Amazon and eBay.

Answer (score 0):

Do what Amazon does. List the full price with styling to de-emphasize it (Amazon has strike-through styling) then list the discounted price more prominently. You can list the saving amount in brackets beside the discounted price.